# Default Picture Viewing App on Android Phones different by vendor?

Tags: android

I had a `Motorola Backflip` before, and while I hated it for a lot of reasons, one thing I liked was the way the Picture Viewer worked. The default one let me add tags and sort images. I traded it in for a `Palm Pre Plus`, and recently upgraded again to an `HTC Inspire 4G`. I thought that since I was going back to an Android phone, I would have this same feature available, but it seems these features I actually liked on the Backflip are not on the Inspire.

Does the default Image viewer differ between different phone vendors, even on the same OS platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: Yes, they can, and often are, different.

Android has a lot of core applications and functionality, but a lot of manufacturers add to, alter, and replace some of that. For instance, HTC has their Sense UI and Motorola has their Motorola Blur UI. They customize various parts of the system like the Lock Screen, the Home Launcher, the Clock application, and the Picture viewing application. And generally you can' use them on other devices (the Sense UI, for instance, is deeply integrated into the HTC Roms, so you can't take their Clock application, for example, and use it on a non-HTC ROM).

My suggestion is that you look in the Android Market for something comparable to the picture viewer that you had on your Backflip.

Comment: Damn. This is dissapointing, to say the least. Any idea if what they use on the Motorola phones is available on the market, and what it might be called?

Comment: I highly doubt it's on the Market. As Pascal MARTIN mentioned, you may have some luck checking the [XDA-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) to see if someone was able to extract the APK and get it running on another ROM, but I did a quick search and didn't find anything. The problem is, these custom apps that manufacturers create tend to rely on other aspects to run correctly, so even if you got the apk and tried to install it, it may not run. The easiest thing to do would be to check the Android Market for something similar. You may even find something you like better.

Answer (score 1):

Android is a platform that's opened enough to let vendors customize it the way they feel *(Google is not forcing all vendors to use the exact same software)*.

For example, many vendors develop some kind of Home/Launcher with additionnaly Features : HTC have their Sense UI, Samsung has its own equivalent, ...

So, yes, it is possible that Motorola used a piece of software they specifically created, as a picture viewer.

Now, maybe you'll be able to find something on the Android Market that would be close to the application you had on your previous phone ?

Or maybe you'd be able to find the corresponding .apk, taken from a Backflip ? Search on [XDA-developpers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) forum, for instance.